# R: How to normalize one dataframe (test set) given the values of a different dataframe (training set)

Tags: r, dataframe, normalize

I have a dataframe representing the test set T, and another dataframe representing the training set D. The columns in these two data sets are exactly the same as they were extracted from the same dataframe.

I use the following codes to normalize the training set D

```
MaxMinNormalize <- function(num) {
  if (is.factor(num)) num
  else ((num - min(num)) / (max(num) - min(num)))
}

D_n <- as.data.frame(lapply(D, MaxMinNormalize))
```

Some columns in the data are factors, others numbers, that's why the normalize function.

I want to apply this normalization step on the test set T, with `min` and `max` values taken from respective columns in training set, not the test set. How should I go about doing that?

Thank you for any pointer!

---

**Edits**: As instructed by @coffeinjunky, the following codes were tried to test out the ability to work with mixed typed columns (numeric and factors):

```
df <- mtcars[,c("mpg", "cyl", "am", "gear")]

df$am <- as.factor(df$am)

df$gear <- as.factor(df$gear)

df1 <- df[1:16,]
df2 <- df[17:32,]

summary(df1)
summary(df2)

new_df <- data.frame(sapply(names(df1), function(col) {
  ifelse(is.factor(df2[[col]]), 
         df2[[col]],
         (df2[[col]]-min(df1[[col]]))/(max(df1[[col]])-min(df1[[col]]))) 

}))

head(new_df)
summary(new_df)
```

But the result is weird: somehow the function is stored in the data frame as well, and the columns' names were lost.

```
> head(new_df)
     sapply.names.df1...function.col...
mpg                           0.3071429
cyl                           1.0000000
am                            1.0000000
gear                          1.0000000
> summary(new_df)
 sapply.names.df1...function.col...
 Min.   :0.3071                    
 1st Qu.:0.8268                    
 Median :1.0000                    
 Mean   :0.8268                    
 3rd Qu.:1.0000                    
 Max.   :1.0000
```

I suspect the `ifelse` to deal with factor columns broke the structure of the data.

Comment: `T` is a reserved word in `R`, indicating `TRUE`. Please don't call your dataframe `T`.

Comment: @coffeinjunky I see, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I have furthermore refined it a bit. It might be helpful to have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probably easiest way is to use pre-existing functionality as it is the most convenient. Here, for instance, we could use functions provided in the [caret](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caret.html) package.

To illustrate, let us get some toy data:

```
# get some test data:
df <- mtcars[,c("mpg", "cyl")]
df1 <- df[1:16,]  # training data
df2 <- df[17:32,] # test data to be scaled
```

Let's have a look to see what we would expect.

```
summary(df1) # some output ommitted
      mpg            cyl     
 Min.   :10.4   Min.   :4.0  
 Max.   :24.4   Max.   :8.0  

summary(df2)
      mpg             cyl       
 Min.   :13.30   Min.   :4.000  
 Max.   :33.90   Max.   :8.000
```

We see that the range (`max - min`) in `df1` for `mpg` is 14, and for `cyl` it is 4. If we look at the max value for `df2`, it is 33.9 for `mpg`. Subtracting the min from `df1`, i.e. 10.4, and dividing by 14, should give us 23.5/14=1.6785. Similar math holds for the other columns and values.

Now, let us use `caret::preProcess` and see if we get the same value.

```
library(caret)
train_stats <- preProcess(df1, method = "range")
new_df1 <- predict(train_stats, df1)
new_df2 <- predict(train_stats, df2)
```

Let's first check if `new_df1` is scaled to the 0-1 range, as it should be.

```
summary(new_df1)
# some output omitted:
      mpg              cyl       
 Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.000  
 Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.000
```

Now let's see if we get the expected values on the test set:

```
summary(new_df2)
# some output omitted:
      mpg              cyl        
 Min.   :0.2071   Min.   :0.0000  
 Max.   :1.6786   Max.   :1.0000
```

Yes, it looks like this worked.

Now, just to show how to implement this `by hand`, consider that we need to go through each column, do an operation, and return the new column. This can often be achieved using a function of the `apply`-family. Since two different dataframes are involved with identical column names, it seems to be an idea to iterate over the column names. For instance,

```
sapply(names(df1), function(x) (...) )
```

will apply `function` with each column name in df1 as argument. Let's use it in the following way:

```
df2[] <- sapply(names(df1), function(col) {
    if(is.factor(df2[[col]])) df2[[col]] else (df2[[col]]-min(df1[[col]]))/(max(df1[[col]])-min(df1[[col]]))})
```

Let's see if this gives the expected result:

```
summary(df2)
      mpg              cyl        
 Min.   :0.2071   Min.   :0.0000  
 Max.   :1.6786   Max.   :1.0000
```

which it does.

Comment: This works great for all the numeric fields, but the factor fields are all converted into double type. I tried to change from `sapply` to `lapply`, but it does not work. Do you have any pointer?

Comment: Just add a control statement into the beginning of the function. It seems that you had done this already in your own function. Changing `sapply` to `lapply` only changes the format of the output, not the function being applied.

Comment: thank you @coffeinjunky, but the codes don't work as expected: the factors seem to screw up the processing. Please see my edits in the question for the details. Thanks!

Comment: great, this works! I accepted the answer. Thank you!